# use Dynamic variable to create a tuple-like variable

Tags: c#, .net, tuples, c#-5.0

I'm trying to create a tuple-like variable using the `dynamic` variable, but I don't know how.

This is the code that I'm trying to recreate using `dynamic` variable

```
var mustEncodeDict = new Dictionary<string, (bool doubleQ, int maxEnc)>();

mustEncodeDict.Add("test1", (true, 3));
mustEncodeDict.Add("test2", (true, 3));
mustEncodeDict.Add("test3", (true, 3));
mustEncodeDict.Add("test4", (false, 3));
mustEncodeDict.Add("test5", (true, 3));
```

I'm trying to use the `dynamic` variable instead of tuple because I want to make the code C# 5 compatible, I know this reason sounds really silly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @GetRektBoy724 welcome to Stack Overflow. Maybe have a look on [`Tuple.Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-3.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Tuple_3__ctor__0__1__2_). Is it what you try to achieve?

Comment: Why must you use `dynamic`? Why not a `struct`?

Comment: Maybe something like `var mustEncodeDict = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>(); mustEncodeDict.Add("test1", new{ doubleQ = true, maxEnc = 3 }); Console.WriteLine(mustEncodeDict["test1"].doubleQ);` if you really want to use `dynamic`

Comment: You can't create variables using `dynamic`. All `dynamic` does is defer compilation until runtime, resolving member names according to the runtime type rather than the compile time type. So whatever your [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is here, `dynamic` isn't the path forward.

Comment: thx @Jimi,lemme test that

Comment: thx so much @Jimi,it works :D

Comment: `dynamic` doesn't make things more or less compatible with .Net 5 or even C# 5. C# is a strongly typed language by design, and you should really try and take advantage of that when writing code.

Comment: ahh ok thx for the advice everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tuple data structure is present since long back, so even if you are targeting .net Framework 4 (C# 4.0), you should be good.

Only the new nice syntax and re-implementation as a value type were introduced later.

Said that:

```
var mustEncodeDict = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<bool, int>>();
mustEncodeDict.Add("test1", Tuple.Create(true, 3));
```

Comment: Ahh lmao idk about this,im so suck at C#.thx for answering but i got it working with `dynamic` :)

Answer (score 0):

The names of the value tuples are compiler constructs that are not part of the tuple but attached to the values.

Look at your code in https://sharplab.io/ to see what's going on behind the scene.

If you want your code to be interoperable between different runtimes or languages (or language versions), you should create a class for that.